# default method in interfaces in java

Tags: java, interface, default

I am attempting to understand default methods in interfaces in Java using the following code, but I am unable to compile it:

```
public interface A {
    default void foo(){
       System.out.println("Calling A.foo()");
    }
}

public class Clazz implements A {
}

class c
{
    public static void main(String[]args)
    {
        Clazz clazz = new Clazz();
        clazz.foo(); // Calling A.foo()
    }
}
```

The compiler produced the following output:

```
c.java:2: error: illegal start of type
    default void foo(){
    ^
c.java:2: error: = expected
    default void foo(){
            ^
c.java:2: error: ';' expected
    default void foo(){
                ^
c.java:2: error: illegal start of type
    default void foo(){
                    ^
c.java:2: error:  expected
    default void foo(){
                     ^
c.java:2: error: = expected
    default void foo(){
                      ^
c.java:2: error: ';' expected
    default void foo(){
                       ^
c.java:3: error: illegal start of type
       System.out.println("Calling A.foo()");
             ^
c.java:3: error: = expected
       System.out.println("Calling A.foo()");
                 ^
c.java:3: error:  expected
       System.out.println("Calling A.foo()");
                         ^
c.java:3: error: illegal start of type
       System.out.println("Calling A.foo()");
                          ^
c.java:5: error: class, interface, or enum expected
       }
```

I am unable to understand these errors. How can I correct the problems in my code?

Comment: @Kon [default methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/defaultmethods.html) allow implementation

Comment: Did you compile your code with Java 8? I tried that code, and all I had to change is remove the public from the interface and class Clazz (to allow them to sit in the same source file as the main class c, which should be public).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`default` modifier doesn't work for java version older than 8, so make sure you're using the right compiler for your source code.